# what is the difference between ubuntu openstack and openstack kilo to build a private cloud?

Tags: openstack, cloud

I am trying to build a private cloud.

I was wondering what is the difference between

ubuntu openstack using maas to build the machines http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack

which have some heavy prerequisites.

And openstack kilo and it's previous versions https://www.openstack.org/software/kilo/

which have no explicit prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're a little confused.  Ubuntu's website simply describes how you can install OpenStack on it.  (You could install OpenStack on some other flavor of Linux if you wanted to.)

OpenStack *Kilo* is like saying Windows 7.  The "7" part tells you which version of Windows we're talking about.  Kilo is a version of OpenStack.

[Versions of OpenStack](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Releases)

I'm currently running OpenStack *Icehouse* since that's what you get if you're on Ubuntu 14.0.2LTS and you don't specifically change the default PPA when installing Juju and related charms.